# Start a browser with a logged proxy in Robot framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, http-proxy, browsermob-proxy, javascript-proxy

i'm facing the current problem: Since i'm under VPN, when i open a browser, a browser popup appears and ask me for the user and password credentials:

[image]

I need to open a browser in robot framework (firefox or chrome is the same) with a logged proxy.

I know that is possible to open a firefox instance with a proxy by using SeleniumLibrary Create Webdriver:

```
${proxy}=   Evaluate    selenium.webdriver.Proxy()  modules=selenium, selenium.webdriver
${proxy.http_proxy}=    Set Variable    localhost:8888  
Create Webdriver    Firefox proxy=${proxy}
```

The problem is that it seems not possible to pass the credentials (user and password) for the proxy login.
Also, like most of the people suggest, i know that is possible to open the browser logged in with the proxy by using the url formatted like (in past i've also used that on different projects):

```
https://proxy_user:proxy_password@url_to_reach.com
```

but for some reason it doesn't work, i still have the browser popup asking me the credentials.

I've also tried by using Input Text Into Alert but it doesn't fill the alert fields:

```
Input Text Into Alert   text=username   action=LEAVE
```

I've also thought that maybe it is possible to do by using some preferencies with chrome or a profile with firefox but i've found nothing about this. Any other method by javascript?
Anyone can help? Thanks a lot